# How can access routes that are not in web.php ( laravel)

Tags: laravel

I found a laravel project that place routes not only in web.php also in another folders and include this files from other
What kind of logic is that
I never see and I never can access their routes
here are folder struture

[image]

can accest routes by this way in laravel?

Comment: `web.php` and `api.php` are not special files. They just happen to be the files that the Laravel boilerplate [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L40) uses, but the boilerplate code is meant for simple starter apps, as your app gets more and more complex it's not uncommon to have more route files as to keep things clean and update your RouteServiceProvider accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create files as `group/admin.php` per needed modules in the `/routes` folder.

Open `/routes/group/admin.php`. Inside this file we will place all admin related routes.

```php
<?php
    
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
Route::prefix("admin")->group(function(){
  Route::get("/", [AdminController::class, "index"]);
});
```

We have separated each module's routes into different route files. More importantly, the application routes are now more readable.

Next, open `RouteServiceProvider.php` inside the `/app/Providers` folder.

Inside this class, search for `boot()` method.

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();
    
    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    
        // Admin Route file 
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/group/admin.php'));
    });
}
```

All done!

Test it out by opening the project in the terminal and typing the command to start development server:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

Then view in the browser at:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`